# Calculate row height in CSS grid with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, grid-layout

I made a small CSS grid framework for my new project but soon after, I have realized it has some shortcomings. Problem is, columns don't occupy whole height of a row which in turn prevents me from creating "blocky" layout and with current setup I can't achieve this with CSS.

I have solved this with some JavaScript, but what troubles me is that this peace of code needs to be executed after the page loads. Which means layout will be a bit messy if there's a lot of content to load.

Also, I'm not great with JavaScript so I'm not sure if I did this properly.

**Here's link to source code on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Jinx/pen/qiotr)**

[NOTE]
I don't want to use any JavaScript libraries

Comment: not very sure but clearfix technique could solve this problem.

Comment: what browser compatibility does this need to be done for?

Comment: you might use a CSS table http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/tables/

Comment: @KashifNaseem clearfix would be for floated elements, I have to use inline-block elements. +Pete browser support is IE8+. +FezVrasta CSS table lack a bit of flexibility I have intended for this project.

Comment: is it a dynamic generated code?

Comment: @FezVrasta yes it will be for joomla

Comment: completly fluid layout like the one on the codepen?

Comment: @FezVrasta why would I use node? I don't see how it would help.

Comment: sorry nevermind, didn't thought about the dynamic need

Answer (score 1):

You can try using css `table` display property stack and use javascript as a fallback to unsupported browsers if required.

```
  display: table;
  display: table-cell;
  display: table-column;
  display: table-colgroup;
  display: table-header-group;
  display: table-row-group;
  display: table-footer-group;
  display: table-row;
  display: table-caption;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEniv

[Browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/css-table)

Comment: Well, the whole idea is to use inline-block element, and CSS tables aren't as flexible for this purpose. + I need to keep things minimal.

Comment: Notice that column offsetting doesn't work (as well as it should) in your example. (most bottom row)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cDZpA/

```
.container { 
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0px;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.333%;
    font-size: 14px; 
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
}

.c1 { background: yellow; }
.c2 { background: purple; }
.c3 { background: red;  }
```

Don't ask me how, but this code I've put down works.

Here your CodePen fixed:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wkbrj